# A sequence of continuous functions cannot converge to a function discontinuous in (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My professor asked me to show that there cannot exist a sequence of continuous functions converging to $f:[0,1]\rightarrow$ {$0,1$} defined to be $0$ at rational and $1$ at irrational. Instead I am trying to prove the following more general theorem which I don't know if it is true.
Theorem:
Let $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that there exist $(a,b)\subset E$ so that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere on $(a,b)$, then it cannot exist a sequence of continuous functions {$f_n$}$\rightarrow f$ pointwise.

Proof:
We start by claiming that  there exists $\epsilon^*>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $x,y \in (a,b)$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)|>2\epsilon^*$. Suppose otherwise then for all $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
 $|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<2\epsilon$. That implies $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ a contradiction.

Assume ${f_n}\rightarrow f$ pointwise and fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta_n^\epsilon$ :=sup{$\delta\mid |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon$}. Clearly since {$f_n$} are continuous for all $n$ we conclude that $\delta_n^\epsilon\neq \emptyset$. So we can define $d_\epsilon$:=inf{$\delta_n^\epsilon$}.Now if $d_\epsilon=0$ then for all $m>0$ there exists $N_m$ and $a_{N_m}, b_{N_m}$ such that $0<|a_{N_m}-b_{N_m}|<1/m$ but $|f_{N_m}(a_{N_m})-f_{N_m}(b_{N_m})|>\epsilon$. Without loss of generality we may assume $lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}N_m=\infty$ and that  $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}(a_{N_m})=L$ because we can always choose a subsequence satisfying that.We note we must have that $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}|f_{N_m}(a_{N_m})-f_{N_m}(b_{N_m})|>\epsilon$, however $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}(a_{N_m})=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}(b_{N_m})=L$ so since $f_n$ are continuous and {$f_n$}$\rightarrow f$ we must have $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}|f_{N_m}(a_{N_m})-f_{N_m}(b_{N_m})|=|f(L)-f(L)|=0$ a contradiction. So we conclude $d_\epsilon\neq 0$

Now restrict $f$ in $(a,b)$ and consider $\epsilon^*>0$ and $x,y\in (a,b)$ such that $|x-y|<d_{\epsilon^*}$ but $|f(x)-f(y)|>2\epsilon^*$, since {$f_n$$(x)$}$\rightarrow f(x)$ there exists $N_0$ such that $n>N_0\Rightarrow|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon^*/2$, similarly there exists $M_0$ such that $n>M_0\Rightarrow|f_n(y)-f(y)|<\epsilon^*/2$  hence for $n>max(N_0,M_0)$ $|f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(y)+f_n(y)-f(y)|>2\epsilon^*$ $\Rightarrow |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f(y)-f_n(y)|>2\epsilon^*$
Therefore $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|>\epsilon^*$. A contradiction hence there cannot exist $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise.

It would be highly appreciated if you could let me know if my proof is correct or point me out any errors I have

Thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of convergence?

Comment: relevant btw: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593527/how-to-prove-that-there-does-not-exist-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-that-c

Comment: also relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77307/existence-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-convergent-pointwise-to-the-indi

Comment: Sorry I ddnt point it out I am talking about pointwise convergence since uniform is clearly impossible

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If $f_1,f_2, \dots$ are continuous on $(a,b)$ and converge point wise everywhere there, then the limit function is continuous on a dense $G_\delta$

Comment: So i guess the theorem I am trying to prove indeed is true. However I am not sure about the proof I made more specifically I am not sure about a part that I claim that if $a_n\rightarrow L$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ and$ f_n$ cts then $f_n(a_n)\rightarrow f( L)$

Comment: You need uniform convergence for that part. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133961/lim-n-to-inftyf-nx-n-fx-if-f-n-to-f-and-x-n-to-x

Comment: google Baire class one, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function and https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783656 and http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~www/programs/undergraduate/1213_honors_presentations/Siuyung_Fung_Honors_Thesis.pdf and http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matlhh/preprints/Baire.pdf and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.877.4255&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: If $f$ is a point-wise limit of a sequence of continuous functions then $f^{-1}\{y\}$ (which is $\{x:f(x)=y\} $) is a $G_{\delta}$-set for every $y.$